# Applying generic decorators conditionally in Autofac based on configuration values

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ioc-container, autofac

I have an application with an [command/handler based architecture](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91). I have the following interface:

```
public interface ICommandHandler<TCommand>
{
    void Handle(TCommand command);
}
```

There are many non-generic implementations of this interface. Those implementations are wrapped by generic decorators such as:

```
public class ProfilingCommandHandlerDecorator<TCommand> : ICommandHandler<TCommand>
{
    private readonly ICommandHandler<TCommand> decoratee;

    public ProfilingCommandHandlerDecorator(ICommandHandler<TCommand> decoratee)
    {
        this.decoratee = decoratee;
    }

    public void Handle(TCommand command)
    {
        // do profiling here
        this.decoratee.Handle(command);
        // aaand here.
    }
}
```

Some of these decorators however should be applied conditionally based on the flag in the config file. I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23406641/how-to-mix-decorators-in-autofac) that refers to applying non-generic decorators conditionally; not about generic decorator. How can we achieve this with generic decorators in Autofac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This most like involves implementing your own `IRegistrationSource`. If you pull the code for Autofac and look at [OpenGenericDecoratorRegistrationSource](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/blob/master/Core/Source/Autofac/Features/OpenGenerics/OpenGenericDecoratorRegistrationSource.cs), that should get you on the right track.