# Applying generic decorators conditionally in Autofac based on generic type constraints

Tags: c#, generics, dependency-injection, ioc-container, autofac

I have an application with an [query/handler based architecture](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=92). I have the following interface:

```
public interface IQueryHandler<TQuery, TResult> where TQuery : IQuery<TResult>
{
    TResult Handle(TQuery query);
}
```

There are many non-generic implementations of this interface. Those implementations are wrapped by generic decorators for logging, profiling, authorization, etc. Sometimes however I want to apply a generic decorator conditionally based on the generic type constraints of the decorator. Take for instance this caching decorator that can only be applied to queries that return a `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` (simply because caching any collection that is mutable doesn't make much sense):

```
public class CachingQueryHandlerDecorator<TQuery, TResult> 
    : IQueryHandler<TQuery, ReadOnlyCollection<TResult>>
    where TQuery : IQuery<ReadOnlyCollection<TResult>>
{
    private readonly IQueryHandler<TQuery, ReadOnlyCollection<TResult>> decoratee;
    private readonly IQueryCache cache;

    public CachingQueryHandlerDecorator(
        IQueryHandler<TQuery, ReadOnlyCollection<TResult>> decoratee,
        IQueryCache cache)
    {
        this.decoratee = decoratee;
        this.cache = cache;
    }

    public ReadOnlyCollection<TResult> Handle(TQuery query)
    {
        ReadOnlyCollection<TResult> result;

        if (!this.cache.TryGetResult(query, out result))
        {
            this.cache.Store(query, result = this.decoratee.Handle(query));
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

What might make it more tricky is that those conditional decorators could be anywhere in the decorator chain. More than often they are one of the decorators in the middle. For instance, this `CachingQueryHandlerDecorator` wraps a non-conditional `ProfilingQueryHandlerDecorator` and should get wrapped by a conditional `SecurityQueryHandlerDecorator`.

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23406641/how-to-mix-decorators-in-autofac) that refers to applying non-generic decorators conditionally; not about applying generic decorators conditionally based on generic type constraints. How can we achieve this with generic decorators in Autofac?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Applying generic decorators conditionally in Autofac based on configuration values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23472611/applying-generic-decorators-conditionally-in-autofac-based-on-configuration-valu)

Comment: @JimBolla: That is not a duplicate IMO. Although both are about handling generic decorator conditionally, this question is explicitly about generic type constraints which very likely need a different way  to handle them.

Comment: The answer would be exactly the same... implement an IRegistrationSource similar to the one recommended in the original question. The only difference will be in the `if` statement. Heck, you could make the implementation for this question and the other share a common abstract base class.

Comment: @JimBolla: Let's wait what Nick has to sat about this. He promised me to give an answer to these questions this weekend.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If I inherited a codebase that had decorator chains, this is what I would hope to see:

```
// Think of this as the "master decorator" - all calling code comes through here.
class QueryHandler<TQuery, TResult> where TQuery : IQuery<TResult>
{
    private readonly IComponentContext context;

    public QueryHandler(IComponentContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public TResult Handle(TQuery query)
    {
        var handler = context.Resolve<IQueryHandler<TQuery, TResult>>();

        if (typeof(TResult).IsClosedTypeOf(typeof(ReadOnlyCollection<>)))
        {
            // manual decoration:
            handler = new CachingQueryHandlerDecorator<TQuery, TResult>(handler);

            // or, container-assisted decoration:
            var decoratorFactory = context.Resolve<Func<IQueryHandler<TQuery, TResult>, CachingQueryHandlerDecorator<TQuery, TResult>>>();
            handler = decoratorFactory(handler);
        }

        if (NeedsAuthorization(query)) { ... }

        return handler.Handle(query);
    }
}
```

Since the order of decoration is important, I want to be able to see it and easily change it and step through it if needed. Even if I'm new to DI, I can probably maintain this code.

However, if you have a jumble of keys and callbacks and container-driven magic, it will be much harder for me to maintain. Just because you *can* use the container for something doesn't mean you *should*.

Finally, notice that my `QueryHandler` class does not implement `IQueryHandler` - this is on purpose. I've come to think of the Decorator pattern as "mostly harmful" in that a lot of times it subverts the Liskov substitution principle. For example, if you use `IQueryHandler` everywhere then a misconfigured DI container could omit an Authorization decorator - the type system won't complain, but your app is definitely broken. For this reason, I like to separate the "call-site abstraction" from the "implementation-site abstraction" (see Event Handler vs Event Raiser on [another of my answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7154912/644812)) and make anything in-between as explicit as possible.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time of answering my question. I do disagree with your "decorator pattern is harmful" statement (although any pattern can be easily abused, that's for sure). Problem however  with your current approach is that it doesn't compile. This is caused by the generic type constraints. This is solvable, but will become quite ugly. And as you already said, we would like to have a code base that is maintainable. But perhaps the problem is that I'm spoiled with Simple Injector :-(.

Comment: @Steven - You mentioned that this problem is solvable, but you didn't provide the solution (to either one of your questions). It seems like this should be a matter of adding an extension method onto Autofac to hide the nasty details behind this, but I would like to know what you ultimately came up with.

Comment: @NightOwl888 We were able to remove the generic type constraints from our decorators by moving type checking and casting to our decorators code. This means that decorators were always applied and an `if` statement inside the decorator would decide whether the decorated logic should be applied. This is error prone and very ugly but worked until we migrated to Simple Injector. We never invested into making a good extension, because I know how fukcing hard it is to make this right.