# How can I change the default "Sorry, my bot code is having an issue" exception message?

Tags: c#, botframework

I need to change the default "Sorry, my bot code is having an issue" exception message. It seems like it is a somewhat complicated process. I have tried to do as it says in this blog post: http://wp.sjkp.dk/change-the-sorry-my-bot-code-is-having-an-issue-in-microsoft-bot-framework/

I don't have knowledge of dependency injection or inversion of control, so this is becoming quite a challenge. I'm using the Bot Builder version 3.5.5.

This is the code from the blog, which I tried to use on my bot:

The PostUnhandledExceptionToUser class:

```
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers;
using Microsoft.Bot.Connector;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Net.Mime;
using System.Resources;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Tiimo.Bot.BotFramework
{
    public class PostUnhandledExceptionToUser : IPostToBot
    {
        private readonly ResourceManager resources;
        private readonly IPostToBot inner;
        private readonly IBotToUser botToUser;
        private readonly TraceListener trace;

        public PostUnhandledExceptionToUser(IPostToBot inner, IBotToUser botToUser, ResourceManager resources, TraceListener trace)
        {
            SetField.NotNull(out this.inner, nameof(inner), inner);
            SetField.NotNull(out this.botToUser, nameof(botToUser), botToUser);
            SetField.NotNull(out this.resources, nameof(resources), resources);
            SetField.NotNull(out this.trace, nameof(trace), trace);
        }

        async Task IPostToBot.PostAsync(IActivity activity, CancellationToken token)
        {
            try
            {
                await this.inner.PostAsync(activity, token);
            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (Debugger.IsAttached)
                    {
                        var message = this.botToUser.MakeMessage();
                        message.Text = $"Exception: { error.Message}";
                        message.Attachments = new[]
                        {
                            new Attachment(contentType: MediaTypeNames.Text.Plain, content: error.StackTrace)
                        };

                        await this.botToUser.PostAsync(message);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        await this.botToUser.PostAsync("My Personal Error Message");
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception inner)
                {
                    this.trace.WriteLine(inner);
                }

                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The DefaultExceptionMessageOverrideModule class:

```
using Autofac;
using Autofac.Builder;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.History;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Scorables.Internals;
using Microsoft.Bot.Connector;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Resources;
using System.Web;


namespace Tiimo.Bot.BotFramework
{
    public class DefaultExceptionMessageOverrideModule : Module
    {
        protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.RegisterType<PostUnhandledExceptionToUser>().Keyed<IPostToBot>(typeof(PostUnhandledExceptionToUser)).InstancePerLifetimeScope();


            RegisterAdapterChain<IPostToBot>(builder, 
                typeof(PersistentDialogTask),
                typeof(ExceptionTranslationDialogTask),
                typeof(SerializeByConversation),
                typeof(SetAmbientThreadCulture),
                typeof(PostUnhandledExceptionToUser),
                typeof(LogPostToBot)
            )
            .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        }

        public static IRegistrationBuilder<TLimit, SimpleActivatorData, SingleRegistrationStyle> RegisterAdapterChain<TLimit>(ContainerBuilder builder, params Type[] types)
        {
            return
                builder
                .Register(c =>
                {
                // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23406641/how-to-mix-decorators-in-autofac
                TLimit service = default(TLimit);
                    for (int index = 0; index < types.Length; ++index)
                    {
                    // resolve the keyed adapter, passing the previous service as the inner parameter
                    service = c.ResolveKeyed<TLimit>(types[index], TypedParameter.From(service));
                    }

                    return service;
                })
                .As<TLimit>();
        }
    }  
}
```

After creating these classes I went to the Global.asax file and put this code:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterModule(new DefaultExceptionMessageOverrideModule());
builder.Update(Conversation.Container);
```

It builds successfully, however when I send a message to the bot I get the following error:

> An exception was thrown while invoking the constructor ‘Void .ctor(Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.IPostToBot,
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.IBotData)’ on type
>   ‘PersistentDialogTask’. —> Valor não pode ser nulo. Nome do parâmetro:
>   inner (See inner exception for details.)

Which I guess it translates to something like

> An exception was thrown while invoking the constructor ‘Void
>   .ctor(Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.IPostToBot,
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.IBotData)’ on type
>   ‘PersistentDialogTask’. —> Value cannot be null. Parameter name: inner
>   (See inner exception for details.)

Is there something wrong with the code? What am I doing wrong? Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid "Sorry, my bot code is having an issue" in Microsoft Bot Framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39609638/how-to-avoid-sorry-my-bot-code-is-having-an-issue-in-microsoft-bot-framework)

Comment: @DanEsparza I don't think so. That user want's to avoid it, I want to change it. There's some differences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using this code for registering the adapter chain:

```
builder
        .RegisterAdapterChain<IPostToBot>
        (
            typeof(EventLoopDialogTask),
            typeof(SetAmbientThreadCulture),
            typeof(PersistentDialogTask),
            typeof(ExceptionTranslationDialogTask),
            typeof(SerializeByConversation),
            typeof(PostUnhandledExceptionToUser),
            typeof(LogPostToBot)
        )
        .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

I believe that at some point the `PersistentDialogTask` was updated and [they added a dependency on an IPostToBot implementation](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/Dialogs/DialogTask.cs#L448) which, in the registration you were using, was not being provided. I took the updated code from the [DialogModule](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Autofac/Dialogs/DialogModule.cs#L341-L352).

If you go over the code you will see that the `EventLoopDialogTask` is the first item in the chain and it doesn't depend on any `IPostToBot` implementation. My guess is that at the time of the post you read, the `PersisteDialogTask` was the first item in that chain.

Comment: It is working great now! I spent way too much time trying to do this, so thank you so much. :)

Comment: How does this solve your issue?  Which one of those types resolved this?

Comment: Fair question. I believe the problem was that the Adapter chain changed during some point and now the PersistentDialogTask depends on an IPostToBot implementation (see [code](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/Dialogs/DialogTask.cs#L448), which with the registration he was using it wasn't provided. I updated the answer with those details.